# Trying the reverse dns lookup at sinatra

Tags: ruby, dns, sinatra, reverse

I made a web application using ruby with sinatra.

The web application is always trying to do reverse dns lookup per a client.

How can i disable it ?

Comment: How do you know it's trying to do that?

Comment: There's no part of Sinatra that does a reverse DNS lookup, so you'll either have to provide more information about the tcpdump and netstat or about the code within the application.